pandas: sorting multi-level columns
I have the following pandas dataframe:
import pandas as pd
data1 = [['01/01/2000', 101, 201, 301],
        ['01/02/2000', 102, 202, 302],
        ['01/03/2000', 103, 203, 303],]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['date', 'field1', 'field2', 'field3'])
df1 = df1.set_index('date')
data2 = [['01/01/2000', 101, 201, 301],
        ['01/02/2000', 102, 202, 302],
        ['01/03/2000', 103, 203, 303],]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['date', 'field2', 'field1', 'field3'])
df2= df2.set_index('date')

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], keys={'group1':df1, 'group2': df2 }, axis=1)
df

This produces:
            group1                  group2
            field1  field2  field3  field2  field1  field3
date                        
01/01/2000  101     201     301     101     201     301
01/02/2000  102     202     302     102     202     302
01/03/2000  103     203     303     103     203     303

I would like to sort the group and fields by a custom order. For level 1 of the column, I tried the following:
group_sort=['group2', 'group1']
m = {k:v for k, v in enumerate(group_sort)}
df = df.sort_index(axis=1, key=lambda x: x.map(m), level=1)
df

This produces the following, which is still the same as the original dataframe:
            group1                  group2
            field2  field1  field3  field1  field2  field3
date                        
01/01/2000  101     201     301     101     201     301
01/02/2000  102     202     302     102     202     302
01/03/2000  103     203     303     103     203     303

For level 0 (the fields) I tried:
field_sort=['field3', 'field2', 'field1']
m = {k:v for k, v in enumerate(field_sort)}
df = df.sort_index(axis=1, key=lambda x: x.map(m), level=0)
df

But this produces:
            group1  group2  group1  group2  group1  group2
            field1  field1  field2  field2  field3  field3
date                        
01/01/2000  201     101     101     201     301     301
01/02/2000  202     102     102     202     302     302
01/03/2000  203     103     103     203     303     303

So my question is - how would I sort both group and fields?
Is there a cleaner, more concise or efficient way of doing this?
What I am expecting as an output sorted as follows:
            group2                  group1
            field3  field2  field1  field3  field2  field1
date                        
01/01/2000  301     201     101     301     201     101
01/02/2000  302     202     102     302     202     102
01/03/2000  303     203     103     303     203     103

Thanks

You forgot to include the output you want/expected output

@Onyambu ive updated it.  basically i want to specify the order a custom order for level 0 and 1 of the columns to sort by.

You could build a multiindex of your required order and reindex the columns with it

@sammywemmy like df.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([group_sort, field_sort]), axis=1)?  seems it may work

isnt what you want simply  df.sort_index(axis = 1, ascending = False)??

@Onyambu no, i want to specify lists for the orders.  what sammywemmy suggested works.  thanks both

Oh I see. you are not sorting. you already have the order. Yes what was suggested is the way to go.

@sammywemmy if you want to add your suggestion as an answer, i will gladly mark it as the answer

One option is with a combination of reindex and sort_index:
(df
.reindex(labels=field_sort,axis=1,level=1)
.sort_index(level=0,axis=1, sort_remaining=False,ascending=False)
)
Out[23]:
           group2               group1
           field3 field2 field1 field3 field2 field1
date
01/01/2000    301    101    201    301    201    101
01/02/2000    302    102    202    302    202    102
01/03/2000    303    103    203    303    203    103

A more robust option would be to create a MultiIndex and reindex with that:
headers = ['group2','group1']
field_sort=['field3', 'field2', 'field1']
df.reindex(columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([headers,field_sort]))
Out[21]:
           group2               group1
           field3 field2 field1 field3 field2 field1
date
01/01/2000    301    101    201    301    201    101
01/02/2000    302    102    202    302    202    102
01/03/2000    303    103    203    303    203    103

